# optional parameters when defining routes

Tags: typescript, routes, deno

I am working on `deno` equivalent of my `node (express)` server application for study purposes and I can't find a way to apply `optional` chunks when defining `routes`.

For example in `express` application i have route: `/search/:start/:records?`

```
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/abc@v1.3.3/mod.ts";
import { search } from "./controllers/data.ts";

const app = new Application();

const PORT = 80;

app.get("/search/:start/:records?", search);

app.start({ port: PORT });
```

For my experimentation with `deno` i picked `lib` [abc](https://deno.land/x/abc@v1.3.3) that seemed similar to `express`.

When runtime is launched my old routes are working, except the optional chunk, they are not optional anymore, instead they need to be provided or error `404` is being returned.

Does someone have experience with handling optional parameters and `deno`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a whole lot about `abc`, but [`oak`](https://deno.land/x/oak) is currently the most commonly-used http server framework for Deno (and I think it would be the analog of Express based on the metric of popularity).

It uses [`path-to-regexp`](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#parameters) for parsing path strings (which is also what Express uses), so it allows for optional parameters using the same syntax with which you're already familiar.

Here's an example of creating a route like the one in your question using Oak, and sending the path parameter values as properties in a JSON response:

```ts
import { Application, Router } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.5.1/mod.ts";

const router = new Router();
router.get("/search/:start/:records?", async (ctx, next) => {
  const { start, records = null } = ctx.params;
  const json = JSON.stringify({ start, records }, null, 2);
  ctx.response.body = json;
  ctx.response.type = "application/json";
  await next();
});

const app = new Application();
app
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods());

await app.listen({ port: 8000 });
```

Comment: clean and simple, in that case i am switching from `abc` to `oak`, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`abc` does not support optional chunks yet.